# Using Random Forest Regression in order to find the correlation between Independent and dependent variables

Tags: random-forest

I'm having trouble in understanding the steps on how to do Random Forest Regression in order to find the correlation between independent and dependent variables, as the title suggest I'm doing this for my bachelor's thesis and I'm kind of stuck. I read about regression trees and Random Forest but they're mostly about prediction, but my thesis is about using Random Forest Regression in order to find which independent variables impacts the dependent variable (in my case the independent variables are weather data such as humidity, precipitation, temepreature, etc. While as the dependent variable is pineapple crop yield). My professor asked me to explained it to her in detail the process. Any help would be appreciated because i'm a slow learner and i really need guidance.

PS: English is my second language, I apologize in advance for my bad grammar.

I watched many videos on youtube and read Breiman's work about Regression Trees and other sources as well, but I still can't grasp the point. I need all the help I can get.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, SO is primarily for programming problems. Your question would be much more likely of getting an answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to Random Forests and was looking up my own question when I came across yours.

My research is to utilize a few different independent variables to predict hospitalizations due to COVID-19 in my county. As you said, I have not really heard of using a random forest to identify which variables impact or do not impact your dependent variable. Have you considered using correlation? For me, I am using a correlation plot to see the relationship between my independent and dependent variables, whereas the random forest will be the model built to predict hospitalizations. The output from a correlogram would show you 2 things- the strength of the relationship between variables, and the direction of the relationship. Correlograms will give you an output from -1 to 1, with 0 being no correlation, -1 being a perfect inverse relationship (as one variable increases the other decreases), and 1 being a perfect direct relationship (as one variable increases the other also increases).

I used the Seatbelts dataset in R (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/UKDriverDeaths.html) to build this correlogram. You can see the relationship between drivers killed and petrol price has a correlation coefficient of -0.39. This tells us the relationship between drivers killed and petrol price has a weak inverse association for this particular dataset.

[image]

Again, I am also new to this work but maybe discussing with some random person online may help us both.